# Make a class library that references but doesn't expose a dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm making a class library for people to use, let's say `A`. It is dependent on another class library I have, called `B`. A lot of my other internal projects use `B` and that is fine because they are all internal-only projects. However, `A` is for public use and I only want people to see the public members of `A` but not `B`.

Is there a way I can do this (or achieve a similar result)?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead if i mark the classes in `B` as `internal`, then my other projects cant reference them.

Comment: Are you saying you have `class A : B`, and you want the public members of `B` to not be available on an instance of `A`?

Comment: You could use `InternalsVisibleTo` in that case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may be what you are looking for.

It will allow you to mark all classes in your internal assemblies as `internal` but still be usable by other assemblies.

Notes

- making "friend" assemblies requires strongly signing for all assemblies
- it does not in any way protects from disassembling or using your inner assemblies via reflection

Comment: this is the type of thing i was looking for. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the .DLL assembly into your .EXE assembly using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).

If you combine this with obfuscation, it might suffice, but can still be disassembled.

Answer (score 1):

Use composition instead of inheritance.

Instead of

```
public class A : B {
   public void Something() { base.SomethingElse(); }
}
```

Do this:

```
public class A {
   private B b = new B();
   public void Something() { b.SomethingElse(); }
}
```